# c++ waiting for thread exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, termination

I wrote a program in C++ under Linux. For thread I am using pthread. 
In the program I start the thread and this thread is running until I call the function, that should stop it. Here you can see my code.

```
bool isRunning = false;
pthread_t thread;

void startThread() {
    isRunning = true;
    int thread_return = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, runThread, NULL);
}

bool stopThread() {
    isRunning = false;
    // wait until the thread will be finished
    return true;
}

void* runThread(void* ptr) {
    while(isRunning) {
        // do smth.
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

When the thread was started, it will do smth. until the value of `isRunning` will be `false` and the main program itself will do other stuff. The problem is, when I call the function `stopThread`, this function just sets `isRunning` to false and not waiting until the thread will finish its task inside the while-loop. 
My question is, how I can say to function `stopThread`, that it should wait for thread exit.

I tried to put `pthread_join` in `stopThread` function after I set `isRunning` to `false`. But sometimes it causes the problem, that the program waits infinitly. Because the thread was finished faster, than the program comes to wait for thread. Because the thread can be on different parts inside the while-loop. So I never know how much the thread need to exit.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand in your question, you should be using the concept of [thread joining](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Joining).

Like so,

```
bool stopThread() {
    int returnCode;
    isRunning = false;
    void *status;
    rc = pthread_join(your_thread, &status);

    // wait until the thread will be finished

    if (rc) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() 
                is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Main: completed join with thread %ld having a status   
            of %ld\n",t,(long)status);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the function `pthread_join`. [Single UNIX specification documentation for pthread_join.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_join.html)

You will need to keep track of the thread id, to make use of this function. A common paradigm seems to be to have a `Thread` class, that encapsulated that information.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you should be able to do a `pthread_join()` on it, but if for some reason that doesn't work you could try adding a `hasFinished` variable (and then waiting on `hasFinished == true` wherever you are closing the thread...)

```
bool isRunning = false;
pthread_t thread;

// TODO FIX: this is a workaround due to pthread_join() not working properly
bool hasFinished = false

void startThread() {
    isRunning = true;
    int thread_return = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, runThread, NULL);
}

bool stopThread() {
    isRunning = false;
    // wait until the thread will be finished
    return true;
}

void* runThread(void* ptr) {
    while(isRunning) {
        // do smth.
    }

    // TODO FIX: this is a workaround because pthread_join() is not working properly
    hasFinished = true;
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

[edit for clarification:]

and wherever you stop thread

```
/**/
// TODO FIX: this following is a workaround due to pthread_join() not working
isRunning = false;

int TimeoutSleep_ms = 100;
// TimeoutSleep_ms * TimeoutCounter is the timeout time, 10 sec for this case
int TimeoutCounter = 100; 

while (!hasFinished && (--TimeoutCounter > 0))
    sleep(100);
// END TODO FIX
/**/
```

Comment: just as an aside/clarification: in this particular case, assuming i had time, i would go with the pthread_join and/or figure out why pthread_join wasn't working.  this is an idiom that can be used in pretty much any threading situation, though, which is why i wanted to give it.

Comment: @0A0D the point is that inside the code where you signal the thread to stop, you then have a way to signal back that you have actually stopped... e.g. in the thread stop code `isRunning = false; while (!hasFinished /* && some timeout condition */);` or probably `while (!hasFinished /* && some timeout condition */) sleep(100);` or something similar so you don't eat up the processor. (i'll edit the reponse to include)

Comment: @0A0D this is why i said "if for some reason that doesn't work" in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: I still think it is useless and will lead to confusion in the long run.

Comment: @0A0D if you have a last minute deadline and don't have time to figure out why pthread_join() isn't working it provides an alternative.  and the OP has mentioned in a comment elsewhere that pthread_join() is not working; i will edit the post to signify that you should mark it as a workaround in comments.

Comment: Bad code is bad code regardless. BTW, it must be working since he accepted my answer.

Comment: @0A0D understandable code that meets a deadline is not "bad", simply a technical debt to be paid off in the next iteration.  i'm pragmatic about these things, and i offered a solution if pthread_join() was not working (as stated by the OP somewhere although i can't find it now...).  however, i am glad to hear the join is working. :)